# Product with universal construction is unique up to isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

After reading [this post from Milewski's blog](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/05/05/understanding-products-and-universal-constructions/), I think the definition of product is defined as follows

Given A and B are objects in a Category. $X$ is a product of A and B if and only if there is a pair of morphisms:

$$\pi_1 :: X \rightarrow A, \quad\pi_2 :: X \rightarrow B$$
and for any "other" object $Y$ with a pair of morphisms
$$q_1 :: Y \rightarrow A, \quad p_2 :: Y \rightarrow B$$

There is a unique morphism $h$, such that
$q_1 = \pi_1 \circ h$ and $q_2 = \pi_2 \circ h$

I highlight "other" in the definition as I also see this in other places [2](http://brendanfong.com/programmingcats_files/cats4progs-DRAFT.pdf). If we have "other" in the definition can we still prove that all the products of $A$ and $B$ satisfying the definition are isomorphic to each other?

My attempt to prove it is to show that if $X$ and $X'$ both satisfying the definition of the product $A \times B$, then we know there is a morphism $h: X \rightarrow X'$ and a morphism $h': X' \rightarrow X$. I want to show that $h' \circ h = id_X$ by choosing $Y=X$ and show that $id_{X}$ is the unique morphism from $X$ to $X$, but it seems that the "other" requirement in the definition prevents me from doing that.

Comment: You proof is more than fine; the wording in the definition could be improved: the 'for any other' does not imply distinct.

Comment: Your proof is right. And your comment about the phrasing of the definitions is quite right! *Pace* @guidoar the word "other" does imply distinct and should have been omitted from the definition. Another very common blooper along these lines is to say, "let $x, y$ be two elements of $X$, then ...": which excludes the possibility that $x = y$ (because, for example, $1$ and $1$ are not two elements of the integers).

Comment: @RobArthan my wording was rather unfortunate. What I intended to say is, indeed, that 'other' should be ommited because it conveys something that is *not* requiered in the definition of product. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @guidoar no worries. I love these cases where we can improve on the precision of our mathematical use of language just by crossing out noise words.

Comment: Although colloquially “other” implies distinct from the one, in mathematics it need not (just like colloquially “or” is exclusive, but in mathematics it almost never is). When one truly wants to say that there is something *else* distinct from the one, we tend so say so explicitly rather than implicitly by the choice of connectives. The word “distinct” tends to show up explicitly. That said, there is no reason to have a potentially confusing definition when one can give a precise one. But if this was stated colloquially rather than formally, that would explain it.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree with you about "or", but your statement about "other" is encouraging incorrect use of mathematical English. I wrote "sloppy" rather than "incorrect" first of all, but it is worse than sloppiness: if an exercise asked a student to list the singleton subsets of $\{1, 2\}$ other than $\{1\}$, would you accept "$\{1\}$, $\{2\}$" as an answer?

Comment: @RobArthan: Again, I think it depends on whether you are speaking colloquially, or you are making a formal definition. If you are making a formal definition of product, I would say that the use of “other” is unfortunate and improvable, but not *necessarily* incorrect. If you are speaking colloquially, then it is potentially misleading. I certainly would encourage people to not use it to avoid potential misunderstandings. (Just as I tell TAs to never phrase a quiz question as “Can you...” lest the student reply “no”.) (cont)

Comment: @RobArthan (cont): so for your query, that again comes down to: are we speaking formally or informally? An exercise phrased as you do would be informal, and I would probably not penalize the student for making that reply, but I would kick myself for poor wording. (If I were asking that question, I would say “different from” precisely for that reason).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I cannot conceive of an example in which "A is other than B" allows A and B to be the same in formal or colloquial English. However, I think we are both agreed that it's better to be precise in mathematical writing. (I like your advice to your TAs $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpful discussion! So I gather from the comments that the "other" here doesn't imply that it is distinct. May I ask a follow-up question: If we define the product by treating "other" to mean "distinct", are the two definitions equivalent? I have trouble coming up with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the term "other" here is not intended to require $Y$ to be distinct from $X$.  So, there is no difficulty carrying out your argument.  This usage of "other" is fairly common in mathematics, though I would personally consider it ambiguous enough to recommend avoiding it in formal mathematical writing.

If you interpret the definition to require that $Y\neq X$ in order to use the universal property, then a product need not be unique up to isomorphism.  For example, consider the following subcategory of the category of sets.  The objects are $A=\{0\},B=\{1\},X=\{2,3\},$ and $X'=\{4,5\}$.  The morphisms are the identity functions, the unique functions from each of $X$ and $X'$ to $A$ and $B$, the constant functions $X\to X$ and $X'\to X$ with constant value $2$, and the constant function $X'\to X'$ and $X\to X$ with constant value $4$.  It is then straightforward to verify that both $X$ and $X'$ are "products" of $A$ and $B$ in this category if you require $Y\neq X$ in the universal property, but are not isomorphic.  For instance, to check that $X$ is a "product" of $A$ and $B$, the only choice of $Y$ you have to consider is $X'$, and the unique map $X\to X'$ (the constant $4$ map) has the required properties.